# DisplayIpaPackagePath not working in Cycle 7 – Service Release 0?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I was looking at this release this AM because we couldn't take the original release due to bug 41319.   I saw the bit in the [release notes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_9/xamarin.ios_9.8/) about the .ipa packages going into a timestamped subfolder (really!? why did you do this), so I followed the directions given to add the `DisplayIpaPackagePath` target to the csproj.

It didn't do anything that output doesn't show up in the output at all.

Here's the end of our csproj:

```
  <Target Name="DisplayIpaPackagePath">
    <Message Text="IpaPackagePath: $(IpaPackagePath)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You will need some extra items in the `.csproj`.  Either:

   a. Add the `<PropertyGroup>` mentioned in the example from the [release notes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_9/xamarin.ios_9.8/):

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <BuildDependsOn>
       $(BuildDependsOn);
       DisplayIpaPackagePath
     </BuildDependsOn>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```

   or

   b. Use a slightly different approach of adding an [`AfterTargets` attribute](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2010/02/18/build-extensibility-with-net-framework-4/) to the `DisplayIpaPackagePath` target:

   ```
   <Target Name="DisplayIpaPackagePath" AfterTargets="Build">
     <Message Text="IpaPackagePath: $(IpaPackagePath)" />
   </Target>
   ```
2. Keep in mind that text from the `Message` task will only appear in the build output if the MSBuild output verbosity is set to "normal" or higher.
3. The example in the release notes is intended primarily for illustrative purposes.  The following example (based on the [closely related KB article](https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/2061038-can-i-change-the-output-path-of-the-ipa-file-)) might be more useful in a practical setting.  This example switches the `Message` task to a `Copy` task and adds a couple conditions on the new target so that it only runs when the current configuration is set to build a `.ipa` file:

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <BuildDependsOn>
       $(BuildDependsOn);
       CopyIpa
     </BuildDependsOn>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <Target Name="CopyIpa" Condition="'$(OutputType)' == 'Exe' And '$(ComputedPlatform)' == 'iPhone' And '$(BuildIpa)' == 'true'">
     <Copy SourceFiles="$(IpaPackagePath)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
   </Target>
   ```

> really!? why did you do this

The bug report linked in the [release notes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_9/xamarin.ios_9.8/) is aimed at discussing that question and the relative pros and cons of the change.  I have left that bug as public for now to provide visibility on the discussion.  But to help keep the bug moving forward smoothly, I would recommend that users not comment directly on the bug report unless they have some specific constructive input to share.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks that did the trick.  I mistakenly thought the `<Target>` element was all that was needed.